# Java Drawing shapes to file of 2D object

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, pdf-generation

I have a play framework application which I want to be able to produce a product label from. I have the label design in illustrator. It consists of a black circle, white writing with a QR code in the middle, also has curved text.

I want to create a high resolution PDF and/or image file of this design on the fly. All most all of the drawing stuff I find for java relates to swing.

Anyone done this?

Comment: By "design in illustrator" you mean Adobe Illustrator? What is the format of this design? Could you please clarify what you already have? Do you want to scale this image in your application or draw it based on this design draft?

Comment: Yes Adobe Illustrator, the drawing is a draft. I now want to draw it programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic class which allows creating an image programatically is **BufferedImage** and the corresponding **Graphics2D** class. You are not forced to use it with Swing. You can easily convert it to common graphic formats like PNG. Then you can save it as an image file or place it in a generated(e.g. with iText) PDF.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

In other words - yes, it can be done.

But if I ware you I would consider exporting the design from Illustrator to a file and use it as a resource in your application. But if you need to scale it programatically you ought to consider using SVG format to avoid loosing quality. Java does not have build-in support for vector images so you should look at
[Apache Batik](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/)